# How to use setOnClickListener in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, fragment

I ran into a problem, I put some buttons in my fragment and in the code file wanted to use them but I had a problem. Do you know some methods of how can I solve it? I use Kotlin

I tried a lot of variants on how to use setOnClickListener in fragments but it didn't work for me. My code looks like this:

```
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

class WorkoutFragment : Fragment(),WorkoutAdapter.OnItemClickListener, WorkoutFragmentView {
    private lateinit var presenter: WorkoutFragmentPresenter
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }

    }



    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout, container, false)


        return v
    }
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            WorkoutFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
    private fun InitRecyclerView(v:View) {
        val recyclerView = v.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerView.adapter = WorkoutAdapter(WorkoutProvider.WorkoutList, this)
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        InitRecyclerView(view)
        presenter = WorkoutFragmentPresenter(this)


        }}
```

Comment: What are you trying to set a click listener on ? Your adapter's items ?

Comment: I have Recycler view placed in a fragment and if i click on one element of Recycler view the text should be shown

Comment: Then your click listener should be handled from your adapter, not your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75237144/how-to-update-textview-in-main-activity-with-button-in-adapter/75239759?noredirect=1#comment132774743_75239759).

Passing the fragment's view into the adapter isn't the best solution IMHO, it's better to pass a click lambda as demonstrated in the above example. In any case, all you have to do after that is just set an onClickListener in the adapter's items.